# React/WordPress PWA does not respond with a 200 when offline

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I am currently trying to build a WordPress theme using React/Redux. Everything is working as expected except for responding with 200 when offline.

The build folder of CRA (Create React App) is located at `/wp-content/themes/pwa/build`.

When online, WordPress loads the index.php for all routes. This registers the `.css` and `.js` from the `build` folder. Here everything is working as expected.

Im trying to understand how to configure CRA / WorkBox to register the service worker at `/` and serve all pages using the `index.html` in the `build` folder whilst offline.

Full url of index.html: `https://example.com/wp-content/themes/pwa/build/index.html`

I can provide a link to the demo if required.

Comment: Let me know if I can provide any other information.

Comment: Hey! Have you found any solution? I try to do the same without success

Comment: I finally resolve this problem. I had to move service worker from theme folder to the main wordpress folder. Here is a good explanation: https://justmarkup.com/log/2016/01/add-service-worker-for-wordpress/

Comment: Hi @drazewski, thanks for sharing your solution. Unfortunately I want it all packaged within the theme folder so this is not going to help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the problem with some help from [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers/#service-worker-script-response).

Pass `scope` option in `/src/serviceWorker.js` of the react app.

```
// navigator.serviceWorker.register(swUrl)
navigator.serviceWorker.register(swUrl, {scope: "/"})
```

Configure Apache to serve the Service-Worker-Allowed header for the deployed service worker.

```
<Files "service-worker.js">
    Header Set Service-Worker-Allowed "/"
</Files>
```